# Multiline `console.table({a: "aaa\naaa", b: "bbb\nbbb"})` for node

Tags: javascript, node.js, command, line

Is there any way to draw multiline tables in node? I tried this:

```js
console.table({a: "aaa\naaa", b: "bbb\nbbb"})
```

But this is just removing all newlines:

[image: node's console.table example data without newlines]

Comment: If there is no existant solution, you can always go the hard path, and build the table ascii-art (strictly speaking, unicode-art) yourself. It's a bit of work though. Maybe a package exists, e.g. [console-table-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-table-printer) (not saying it's good, just the first related package i found)

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION #1**

Try this, but not sure if its a good solution:

```js
console.table(
  {
    a: "aaa",
    "": "aaa",
    b: "bbb",
    " ": "bbb"
  }
)
```

Output:

[image]

**SOLUTION #2**

The idea is not to mess with the default index and create own column called `label`.

```js
console.table([
  { Label: "a", Values: "aaa" },
  { Values: "aaa" },
  { Label: "b", Values: "bbb" },
  { Values: "bbb" },
]);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is quite an interesting idea and could be build upon!

Comment: Thanks again for such a neat idea, I posted a longer script which automatizes your solution for generic input and nice output for different lengths of strings

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the amazing idea of Dheemanth Bhat, which this solution builds upon:

```js
/**
 * @param {object} data
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614444/multiline-console-tablea-aaa-naaa-b-bbb-nbbb-for-node
 */

export function consoleTableNewline(data) {
  var tmp = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var val = data[i];
    var parts = val.split('\n');
    var maxLen = parts.reduce((acc, cur) => Math.max(cur.length, acc), 0);
    parts = parts.map(x=>x.padEnd(maxLen));
    for (var j=0; j<parts.length; j++) {
      var part = parts[j];
      var key = i;
      var obj = {};
      if (j == 0) {
        obj.key = key;
      }
      obj.val = part;
      tmp.push(obj);
    }
  }
  console.table(tmp);
}
```

It takes care of creating a nice output (all lines are exactly the same length, otherwise it looks highly distorted).

[image: node command line demo]

Answer (score 2):

Based off the other answers I ended up using this. Thanks for the prior work!

Should work for any list of objects with any arbitrary key/value pairs.

Can pass an optional maxColWidth `consoleTableWithWrapping(change, 90) // 90 chars max`

```
function wrapItemToMultipleRows(item, maxCellWidth) {
  const isRemainingData = Object.values(item).find(value => {
    return value && value.length > 0;
  });

  if (!isRemainingData) {
    return [];
  }

  const itemRow;
  const remaining;
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    itemRow[key] = value?.slice ? value.slice(0, maxCellWidth) : value;
    remaining[key] = value?.slice ? value.slice(maxCellWidth) : value;
  });

  return [itemRow, ...wrapItemToMultipleRows(remaining, maxCellWidth)];
}

function consoleTableWithWrapping(data, maxColWidth = 90) {
  const tableItems = data.reduce((prev, item) => {
    return [...prev, ...wrapItemToMultipleRows(item, maxColWidth)];
  }, []);

  console.table(tableItems);
}
```

```
consoleTableWithWrapping([
  {
    sheet: 'One',
    cell: 'C8',
    old: 'no result?',
    new: '',
  },
  ...
]);

┌─────────┬─────────────┬────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ (index) │    sheet    │  cell  │                     old                      │                        new                        │
├─────────┼─────────────┼────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│    0    │    'One'    │  'C8'  │                 'no result?'                 │                        ''                         │
│    1    │    'One'    │ 'I140' │               '=Expenses!B16'                │                  '=Expenses!B8'                   │
│    2    │    'One'    │ 'C141' │  "Enter living expenses in the 'Expenses' "  │    "Enter living expenses in the 'Expenses' "     │
│    3    │     ''      │   ''   │  'tab below – total monthly living expense'  │    'tab below - total monthly living expense'     │
│    4    │     ''      │   ''   │    '\ns will flow through to this field.'    │      '\ns will flow through to this field.'       │
│    5    │    'One'    │ 'C142' │ 'Other significant expenses \r\nEnter other' │    'All fixed and other significant expenses'     │
│    6    │     ''      │   ''   │  " significant expenses in the 'Expenses' "  │   ' \r\nEnter fixed and other significant exp'    │
│    7    │     ''      │   ''   │ 'tab below – total monthly oth\ner signifi'  │    "enses in the 'Expenses' tab below – tota"     │
│    8    │     ''      │   ''   │  'cant expenses will flow through to this '  │    'l m\nonthly fixed and other significant e'    │
│    9    │     ''      │   ''   │                   'field.'                   │    'xpenses will flow through to this field.'     │
│   10    │    'One'    │ 'F142' │  '=IF(AND(OR(G142="",G142=0),OR(I142="",I1'  │    '=IF(AND(OR(G142="",G142=0),OR(I142="",I1'     │
│   11    │     ''      │   ''   │  '42=0)), "Other significant expenses from'  │    '42=0)), "All fixed and other significant'     │
│   12    │     ''      │   ''   │ `\n the 'Expenses' tab", IF(AND(OR(G142=""`  │    `\n expenses from the 'Expenses' tab", IF(`    │
│   13    │     ''      │   ''   │  ',G142>=0),I142>0), "Other significant ex'  │    'AND(OR(G142="",G142>=0),I142>0), "Other '     │
│   14    │     ''      │   ''   │ `p\nenses from the 'Expenses' tab","NOTE: `  │    "s\nignificant expenses from the 'Expenses"    │
│   15    │     ''      │   ''   │  'Enter value of expense in the adjacent c'  │    `' tab","NOTE: Enter value of expense in `     │
│   16    │     ''      │   ''   │                  'el\nl"))'                  │             'th\ne adjacent cell"))'              │
│   17    │    'One'    │ 'I142' │               '=Expenses!B46'                │                  '=Expenses!B25'                  │
```

Comment: I would upvote if it wasn't for the ugly types interspersed into JavaScript. Try learning JSDoc for readable code. You can simply use `@template Type` etc.

Comment: haha exactly the type of reply I expect on stackoverflow :D

We've chosen to directly use TS types and this was just copied from our codebase. tbh I haven't looked too hard at JSDoc so thanks for the heads up.

I've edited out the types, so my answer if officially 'type system agnostic'.

Comment: Thank you, huge upvote! JSDoc is as simple as "convert this TypeScript code to JSDoc" in OpenAI/Playground lol

Answer (score -2):

You can try this way.

1. Array of objects.

   ```
   let a = {firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Smith"};
   let b = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Smith"};
   let c = {firstName:"Emily", lastName:"Smith"};
   console.table([a, b, c]);
   ```

[image]

2. Object whose properties are objects

   ```
   var family = {};
   family.a = {firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Smith"};
   family.b = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Smith"};
   family.c = {firstName:"Emily", lastName:"Smith"};
   console.table(family);
   ```

[image]

Comment: This is neither node nor multiline, did you read the question?

Comment: Give it a try mate and see if it prints the same thing in your node similar to the other answer mentioned above. I tried over my browser console for easiness, thats all.